# Lost beween useWeb3ReactCore and getWeb3

Tags: web3js, truffle, web3-providers, uniswap

I am learning Solidity and DAPPs.

I have tried to create a project with truffle, with this command:

```
$ truffle unbox react
```

Here is what i see in generated code:

```
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";
...
const web3 = await getWeb3();
```

Everything works fine !

I have looked at some popuplar projects like uniswap and here is what i've found in source code:

```
import { useWeb3React as useWeb3ReactCore } from '@web3-react/core'
...
const { active, error, activate } = useWeb3ReactCore()
```

I do not understand the difference between this 2 ways for working with Web3...

Thanks a lot